# Find number by solving the pattern

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I need to solve the pattern in given format

```
98     |    54     |   78
7641   |    3120   |   5402
714    |    494    |   726
```

---

```
43     |    56     |   02
4910   |    0298   |   7614
391    |    005    |   596
```

---

```
35     |    78     |   38
9081   |    4391   |   4602
234    |    823    |   ???
```

I have to find the last number with question mark.

**Edit**

Image  source

[image]

Comment: Do the "-" belong to the puzzle or are they just separators?

Comment: Yes "-" it's a separator, used for formating, not belong to puzzle.

Comment: If you did not make this problem up, please provide a citation for the source.

Comment: Actually I got the question from quiz.

Comment: I have uploaded the image

Comment: As in a school quiz?

Comment: Is this strictly math? I ask because I don't want to go down a rabbit hole of discovering patterns within the numbers themselves only to find out later that the answer required knowledge of something completely different, like patterns in the periodic table or sports stats.

Comment: I think the question based on general mathematics and asked to general audience, so I hope it wont be based on  periodic table or sports stats. Actually I am not having much information or clue about the puzzle, but only the image provided above.

Comment: Mind if I ask what kind of class this was given in? I need to know how to approach the problem. How I've been doing it so far hasn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Did you see someone writing the puzzle in front of you? Of or la the case, maybe you can have clue on time spend To write numbers. Like if he wrote every number fast and spend time on the third each time.

Comment: There is no clue other than the given image, I got this image by WhatsUp.

Comment: In the middle box of the third row, are you sure the number is "4391"? I.e. is the symbol preceding the 4 a mistake, or is it possibly important?

Comment: If it is unimportant than both middle values for 78 are  shifted by 1. Maybe that's something important... :/ 5402 - 1 on each position is 4391.

Comment: @gogators It looks to me like that's simply a mistake by the puzzle creator - seems like a scratched 9. Whether he messed up some "math", or simply decided to slightly alter the "calculation" is of course subject of speculation :P (Note - I have no relation to this puzzle, this is purely from a solver's perspective)

Comment: It seems number of digits is kinda key. Otherwise, there are no reason to write "02" or "005" instead of "2" or "5"

Comment: 4391 is a prime number. All dreams of solving it has broken already

Comment: I have upload the original image of the puzzle.

Comment: With that leading 0´s, eventually we have to simply read the numbers from right to left. 005 -> 500

Comment: Wouldn't that make 3120  0213 and kinda beat the purpose? @Doomenik Not that I didn't try that already anyway. :D

Comment: @Morfium yes kinda, actually simply trying out everything. Like reading the numbers horizontally, vertically or sum the boxes together. Even tried some weird diagonal multiplications :D

Comment: @Doomenik Yeah as awell as partial sums with multiplication and shifted sums from top to bottom or weird modulos all  over the numbers. It is kinda tricky.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> 304.5671786568776109607614404480079620217332903018752941134...

Because

> Those are clearly 3 by 3 matrices. 
>  The determinants of the first two matrices are respectively -10154144 and 8656182, assuming those are aranged in an arithmetic sequence, we want the third one to be 27466508. 
>  The determinant of the third matrix is (196389516 - 554633$x$)  (here I replaced ??? by $x$ for readability reasons). 
>  Solving for x gives the value 168923008/554633 which is roughly 304.5671786568776109607614404480079620217332903018752941134...

Comment: I think it's not that easy

Comment: What do you consider to be the "first two matrices"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the answer either, but it's a pattern that completes the picture anyway, and as I thought it was pretty funny I decided to post it anyway, the matrices are the numbers written with a gray background in the question (doesn't look good in comments sorry)